# Smart gwt how to add image to a grid cell depending on data

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

Data which is received for the "count" column is an int ( 0, 1, 2, ...). For cells with 0 should show nothing and when data is > 0 it should show an image.

```
  count.setImageURLPrefix("silk/");
  count.setImageURLSuffix(".png");
```

This way it I should add same image with different names ( 2.png , 1.png etc.)

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have already received the value of count, then while loading the data into grid, you can directly use the [setAttribute](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/core/DataClass.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method and provide the image to use.

You will need to define a hidden field for storing int values of the count and image field for displaying image on UI.

Here, count image would be a listGridField added to a ListGrid and can be defined as:

```
private ListGridField count = new ListGridField("count", "Count");
count.setType(ListGridFieldType.IMAGE);
count.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
count.setDefaultValue("blank.png");
count.setCanEdit(false);
```

While loading the data, it's value can be set as:

```
ListGridRecord recordTemp = new ListGridRecord();
//add logic to check count int value and set the value accordingly below
recordTemp.setAttribute("count","1.png");
//set other existing attributes
//...
dataSource.getInstance().addData(recordTemp);
```

Also, if the value of count is updated dynamically, then changedHandler() can be added to set the attribute value accordingly.

Comment: Just found out that it can be done by overriding   
    protected Canvas createRecordComponent(final ListGridRecord record, Integer colNum)  btw thanks !